# 16.04 TouchPad not working after booting from sleep

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

my touchpad stops working after every boot from sleep.

its really annoying to restart it every time.

is there a way to disable and enable the touchpad from terminal?

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't "resume" from sleep so you need to hard/cold boot it?

Comment: it resumes but my touchpad stops working

Comment: can you run `xinput` and post the results into your question?

Comment: I guess I need to use xinput --disable and --enable